# Saving string in flatMap block to database in api call using Combine Swift

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to fetch a value from local database and when not found wants to save it to local database and return it. All of these I am doing in Interactor file and actual saving or fetching is done in seperate file. Following is my code:

```
public func fetchCode(codeId: String) -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error> {
    //Get code from localdb
    codeStorageProvider.fetchCode(codeId).flatMap { (code) -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error> in
        if let code = code {
            return Just(code).mapError{ $0 as Error }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        //If not found in db, Get code from server
        let code = self.voucherCodeProvider.fetchVoucherCode(codeId: codeId)
        return code.flatMap { code in
            //save the code to local db
            self.codeStorageProvider.saveVoucherCode(code, codeId)
            return code
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        //return code to presenter
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

I am getting following error in flatMap:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `saveVoucher` doesn't return a Publisher and you are not interested in knowing when the operation is completed, there's no need to use `flatMap` but you can use `handleEvents` and call the side effect to save the code from there. Something like this:

```
func fetchLocal(codeId: String) -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error> {
  return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func fetchRemote(codeId: String) -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
  return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func saveLocal(code: String, codeId: String) {
  // Save to BD
}

func fetch(codeId: String) -> AnyPublisher<String?, Error> {
  return fetchLocal(codeId: codeId)
    .flatMap { code -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> in
      if let code = code {
        return Just(code)
          .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      } else {
        return fetchRemote(codeId: codeId)
          .handleEvents(receiveOutput: {
            saveLocal(code: $0, codeId: codeId)
          })
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
    }
    .map(Optional.some)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fabio, it works great, I didn't know about handleEvents earlier